Should rest mass be included in calculation of entropy in cosmology?
In cosmology, $$s={\rho+p-\mu n\over T}$$ is  a very useful quantity. However, I feel like rest mass shouldn't be included in the entropy because that is very counterintuitive.

I don't have a fully rigorous answer, but intuitively it does make sense to me to include rest mass in the entropy. Say you want to compute the density of states $\rho$ at energy $E$. If $E\gg m$, then there will generically be a lot of momentum eigenstates, since $E \sim p$ and $\rho(E) \sim p^2$. If $E$ is equal to $m$, then there will only be on eigenstate, the state with $p=0$. So comparing the rest mass to the temperature should give you a sense of which regime you're in for how entropy depends on the energy.

@Andrew I think I have understood this rigorously, I write a brief answer to this. On the formal aspect, we have to include the rest mass. I'm only asking this question because the formal result seems counterintuitive. Now we can see that having the rest mass in entropy can still ensure that the entropy of matter will vanish in very low temperature.

For fermion, μ
will become larger than rest mass m to ensure the conservation of particle number, for bosons, μ
will instead approach m and there will be Bose- Einstein condensation. In either case, in low temperature, the contribution of rest mass of entropy will be cancelled by the chemical potential.
Quantitative details will be added.
